# need of Expression in InputExtensions.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Method syntax:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
)
```

Implementation code:

```
Your name: <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
```

What is the need of Expression's instance in TextBoxFor or LableFor first argument? Cant it be implemented in other way? What is the role this expression is playing here?

Comment: what is the other way you are looking for ?

Comment: I am just curious to know the reason. nothing specific

Answer (score 1):

Using `Html.TextBoxFor` essentially applies a function to each textbox to apply a title to it.  This is why you have to specify a function (in this case, a lambda).  You need to have a ViewModel in order to use it.

If you want to avoid using a `Function`, you can use a plain old `Html.TextBox`, but you don't get all the fancy binding that comes with `TextBoxFor` for free.  This just adds an HTML TextBox to the page.

You can read up on `TextBox` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and `TextBoxFor` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)